# Changing directory

Tags: command-line, directory, cd-command

```
~$ cd downloads
bash: cd: downloads: No such file or directory
~$ ls
Desktop    Downloads         Music     Public     Videos
Documents  examples.desktop  Pictures  Templates
~$ cd downloads
bash: cd: downloads: No such file or directory
```

Why is the directory not being changed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Linux file names are case sensitive. The directory isn't named `downloads` but `Downloads`.

Comment: kind of feeling stupid of asking this question. thank you very much sir.

Comment: Linux *can* have case-insensitive file systems (for example if you mount a FAT32-formatted USB thumb drive), but most Linux file systems are case sensitive.

Answer (score 9):

Directories are case sensitive in Linux, run `cd Downloads`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because Linux systems are case-sensitive. So to change `bash`'s current working directory from `~/` to `~/Downloads` run:

```
cd Downloads
```