# How to ignore case in directory paths?

Tags: command-line, case-insensitive

I’m new to Linux/Ubuntu. To my knowledge it’s not possible to make file or folder with only difference in case e.g. I can’t create the files `Text.ini` and `text.ini` (well you can but it will not work, it gives you an error), so why does the terminal care about case when you write path to something e.g. `cd folder/folder` but if the second `folder` starts with capital F then command doesn’t work?

In Windows it doesn’t matter with capital letters or not it works, so is there any way for the terminal to ignore case if the names are correct?

Comment: This is the difference between Windows and Ubuntu (any Linux). Ubuntu file and folder names are case sensitive. That is `Text.ini` and `text.ini` are indeed two different files.

Comment: In Unices you can very well do e.g. `touch Text.ini text.ini`, this will create these files and not throw any error because file (and directory) names are case-sensitive. To my knowledge there’s no easy way to change that behaviour. Are you asking for a way for just the `bash` shell to ignore case in filenames?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/590364/changing-directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to make the terminal autocomplete behave in a case-insensitive manner which gets close to what you are most likely looking for. Add the line

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

to `/etc/inputrc` and start a new terminal. After that,

```
cd foldTab/foldTab
```

will get you to the correct directory even if the second `folder` is in reality `Folder`. You'll see the autocompletion change the directory name on the fly accordingly.

Comment: I added it to the `.inputrc`file into my home and it work as well.